# Quantum theory of gamma radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

1. Quantummechanics can explain the radiation in atoms. Electrons are kept bounded by the electric interaction of protons. The wave function of the electron is coupled to the vectorpotential of the photon field. This coupling is responsible for the radiation process.
2. What about gamma radiation however? Protons and neutrons are held together by strong force. However, in an excited quantum state, the system can emmit gamma photons. The puzzle here is that the electric field plays no role in the nucleus (for example: deuterium), but still electromagnetic radiation emerges.

Could you explain this phenomenon? Why is photon emmitted in the process? The photon plays no role in the strong force. What is the quantum theory of gamma radiation? (Analogous to quantumelectrodynamics)

Comment: why would E&M play no role?

Comment: How does it show up in tricium or deuterium? There is one proton in that case. But, deuterium is not radiactive according to the literatury.